# WPF MultiDataTrigger animation incorrect behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I need a small square inside a Canvas to be animated depending on View-Model's properties, here's XAML

```
<Style x:Key="FlashingRectStyle">
 <Style.Triggers>

                <!-- HasPath & IsBig -->

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=HasPath}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsBig}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="20" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="20" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="190" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="115" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="35" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <!-- HasPath & Not IsBig -->

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=HasPath}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsBig}" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="77" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="73" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="138" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="57" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="97" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="53" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <!-- Not HasPath-->

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasPath}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="105" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="75" />
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

And usage

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource FlashingRectStyle}" Width="30" Height="20" />
</Canvas>
```

The defaults for HasPath and IsBig are both True and the first animation block "HasPath & IsBig" animates correct. 
Also if I change IsBig to false "HasPath & Not IsBig" does begin animating.
 But if I then change back IsBig to true - nothing happens and "HasPath & Not IsBig" keeps animating. 
Also if I set HasPath to false it should fire "Not HasPath" but it doesn't. How do I make it switch animation on fly when properties changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the previous storyboard in the [`ExitActions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.exitactions(v=vs.110).aspx) before adding a new one:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=HasPath}" Value="True" />
      <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsBig}" Value="False" />
   </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
   <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BeginStoryboardName">
         <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" 
                                           Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
               <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="77" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
               <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="73" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
               <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="138" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                                           Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
               <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="57" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
               <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="97" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
               <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="53" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
   </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
   <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
      <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginStoryboardName"/>
   </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: By the way, can you also please tell if there's any way to make a square disappear for 1 second before a DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame animates?

Comment: @IvanZ - If I understand, you want to delay the time it starts?  You can set the [BeginTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the animation you want to delay: `BeginTime="0:0:1"`

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I can see setting begin time just delays the animation start, but I need each animation frame to be delayed for 1 sec. I suppose I should add another KeyFrames collection and toggling Visibility.

Comment: Could you change the `Duration` from 3 to 6 and just space out the `KeyTime`s (0:0:0, 0:0:2, and 0:0:4 respectively)?